# Prove that the MLE of the lambda parameter of Gamma Distribution is unbiased

Tags: statistics, expected-value, gamma-distribution, parameter-estimation

Apologies for using screenshots, I just don't have time to remember and look up all of the formatting tips.
[image]

Alpha is known. Taking the expected value of the MLE I get :

[image]

**My first question** is what am I doing wrong as I've highlighted in red? My professor is getting a different integral than me:

[image]

I asked him and all he mentioned was that it was because summation of xi was in the denominator, which still doesn't make sense how he magically came up with 1/t instead of 1/summation of xi!

**My second question.** Even if taking his integral and solving for it using integration by parts I keep getting an integral that requires repeat integration by parts! How can I solve this integral?

[image]

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote does not make sense because the $X_i$ are **random variables**.  If I asked you to compute for some continuous random variable $Y$ with density $f_Y(y)$ the expectation $\operatorname{E}[Y^2]$, what would you write?  You would write $$\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \int_{y \in \Omega} y^2 f_Y(y) \, dy,$$ where $\Omega$ is the support of $Y$.  You would **not** write $$\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \int_{y \in \Omega} Y^2 f_Y(y) \, dy.$$

Now, recall that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are independent and identically distributed Gamma random variables with common shape parameter $\alpha$ and common rate parameter $\lambda$, i.e. $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \lambda), \\ f_X (x) = \frac{\lambda^\alpha x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}, \quad x > 0,$$ then the sum $$T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n\alpha, \lambda)$$ is also gamma distributed, but with shape $n\alpha$ and rate $\lambda$.  Thus the density of $T$ is $$f_T(t) = \frac{\lambda^{n\alpha} t^{n\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda t}}{\Gamma(n\alpha)}.$$  The expectation of $1/T$ is then
$$\operatorname{E}[1/T] = \int_{t=0}^\infty \frac{1}{t} f_T(t) \, dt = \int_{t=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{n \alpha} t^{n\alpha - 2} e^{-\lambda t}}{\Gamma(n \alpha)} \, dt.$$  To evaluate this integral, we employ a little trick:  we write the integrand as
$$\frac{\lambda^{n \alpha} t^{n\alpha - 2} e^{-\lambda t}}{\Gamma(n \alpha)} = \frac{\lambda}{n\alpha - 1} \frac{\lambda^{n\alpha - 1} t^{(n\alpha-1)-1} e^{-\lambda t}}{\Gamma(n \alpha - 1)},$$ where we have employed the property that $\Gamma(z) = (z-1)\Gamma(z-1)$.  Then the second factor $$\frac{\lambda^{n\alpha - 1} t^{(n\alpha-1)-1} e^{-\lambda t}}{\Gamma(n \alpha - 1)}$$ is the density of a gamma-distributed random variable with shape $n\alpha - 1$ and rate $\lambda$, thus integrates to $1$ over its support.  It follows that $$\operatorname{E}[1/T] = \frac{\lambda}{n\alpha-1}$$ and $$\operatorname{E}[n\alpha/T] = \frac{n\alpha}{n\alpha-1} \lambda.$$  Thus, this estimator is in fact **biased** for the rate parameter $\lambda$.  The bias is especially large when $\alpha$ is small, something that is easily seen by performing a simulation.

I honestly do not know how your professor could have made such a mistake.  It is **well-known** that the MLE for the rate parameter of a gamma distributed sample is biased.  The reciprocal of the sample mean is inverse gamma distributed.  When I look at the solution you furnished, it is clear that there is an error:  the addition of iid gamma random variables does not change the rate, but the shape, in as much as the sum of iid exponential random variables makes a gamma distribution with shape equal to the number of exponential variables added together; e.g. if $$Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_\alpha \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda), \\ f_Y (y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda}, \quad y > 0,$$ then $$X = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_\alpha \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \lambda)$$ and in turn, $$X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$$ is simply the sum of $n\alpha$ iid exponential random variables hence is gamma with **shape** $n\alpha$, not rate $n\lambda$.

Comment: For an example of how to perform the simulation in *Mathematica*, we can evaluate `Mean[2/Mean[#] & /@ Partition[RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[2, 1], 10^6], 5]]` which corresponds to $200000$ simulations with $n = 5$, $\alpha = 2$, $\lambda = 1$.  The result will be close to $n\alpha/(n\alpha - 1) = 10/9 \approx 1.1111$, but if the estimator were unbiased, the result would be close to $1$ instead.

Comment: heropup, once again such an excellent write-up! I had no clue the professor let T = summation of Xi but now it makes sense! One question: I understand that summation of (capital) Xi is a random variable that should not be integrated over but couldn't summation of (lower case) xi stand in for t for the integral? Was the changing of summation of xi's to t done to make the integration easier?

Comment: Oh and you are correct. The question should read "Prove MLE is biased" not unbiased. Sorry, heropup! You are my savior!

Comment: @user152810 No; the point is that if you were to calculate the expectation of $1/T$, you must write $$\operatorname{E}[1/T] = \int_{t=0}^\infty \frac{1}{t} f_T(t) \, dt,$$ and you must have a factor of $1/t$ in the integrand that matches the variable of integration.  Whether we use $X_i$ or $x_i$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @user152810 Whether or not the estimator is biased does not change the fact that the calculation by the professor, as you have communicated it, is incorrect.

Comment: Ok the reason why I ask is because if I was taking a test there is no way I would think to suddenly designate $T = \sum X_i$ out of nowhere. As silly as it sounds if during a test I would probably keep the sum in there until I see that it has become too unwieldy to use for integration and then substitute for T/t. Is my thinking correct? Or am I still not understanding?